# Set drawing in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the next code, I display the contents of two sets `A` and `B` respectively, and the arrows that determine the mapping between their elements...

What is left, is to draw the two sets (namely, two ellipses - one in the left that encloses `ai`'s and `xi`'s and one in the right that encloses the `bi`'s and the `yi`'s). The names of the two sets `A` and `B` have to be displayed after the bottom of the two ellipses. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning,graphs,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,arrows.meta,arrows,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{greektex}
\usepackage[american,greek,greek.polytoniko]{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tikzset{every loop/.style={min distance=15mm,looseness=10}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-latex ,auto ,node distance =0.7cm and 5cm, on grid,semithick ,
state/.style ={circle, draw, color=blue , fill=blue, text=white , minimum width =0.2 cm}]
\node[state] (a1) [label=left:$\alpha_1$]{};
\node[state] (a2) [below =of a1][label=left:$\alpha_2$]{};
\node[state] (a3) [below =of a2][label=left:$\alpha_3$]{};
\node[state] (adots) [below =of a3][label=left:$\vdots$]{};
\node[state] (an) [below =of adots][label=left:$\alpha_n$]{};
\node[state] (b1) [right =of a1][label=right:$\beta_1$]{};
\node[state] (b2) [below =of b1][label=right:$\beta_2$]{};
\node[state] (b3) [below =of b2][label=right:$\beta_3$]{};
\node[state] (bdots) [below =of b3][label=right:$\vdots$]{};
\node[state] (bn) [below =of bdots][label=right:$\beta_n$]{};
\node[state] (x1) [below =of an,yshift=-0.5cm][label=left:$x_1$]{};
\node[state] (x2) [below =of x1][label=left:$x_2$]{};
\node[state] (x3) [below =of x2][label=left:$x_3$]{};
\node[state] (xdots) [below =of x3][label=left:$\vdots$]{};
\node[state] (xn) [below =of xdots][label=left:$x_n$]{};
\node[state] (y1) [below =of bn,yshift=-0.5cm][label=right:$y_1$]{};
\node[state] (y2) [below =of y1][label=right:$y_2$]{};
\node[state] (y3) [below =of y2][label=right:$y_3$]{};
\node[state] (ydots) [below =of y3][label=right:$\vdots$]{};
\node[state] (yn) [below =of ydots][label=right:$y_n$]{};
\path [dashed] (a1) edge (b1); \path [dashed] (b2) edge (a2);
\path [dashed] (b3) edge (a3); \path [dashed] (an) edge (bn);
\path (x1) edge (y1); \path (y2) edge (x2);
\path (y3) edge (x3); \path (xn) edge (yn);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @DungVu's answer, it is possible to use the `fit` library, which allows you to create a node that includes all the others. Here, as they are aligned, you just have to include one from above and below. 
I chose the second `(a2)` and second last `(xdots)` to have a prettier ellipse for my taste.

```
\node[fit={(a2)(xdots)},draw, ellipse,minimum width=3cm](left){};
```

[image: ellipses]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning,graphs,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,arrows.meta,arrows,shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
%\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage{greektex}
%\usepackage[american,greek,greek.polytoniko]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tikzset{every loop/.style={min distance=15mm,looseness=10}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-latex ,auto ,node distance =0.7cm and 5cm, on grid,semithick ,
state/.style ={circle, draw, color=blue , fill=blue, text=white , minimum width =0.2 cm}]
\node[state] (a1) [label=left:$\alpha_1$]{};
\node[state] (a2) [below =of a1][label=left:$\alpha_2$]{};
\node[state] (a3) [below =of a2][label=left:$\alpha_3$]{};
\node[state] (adots) [below =of a3][label=left:$\vdots$]{};
\node[state] (an) [below =of adots][label=left:$\alpha_n$]{};
\node[state] (x1) [below =of an,yshift=-0.5cm][label=left:$x_1$]{};
\node[state] (x2) [below =of x1][label=left:$x_2$]{};
\node[state] (x3) [below =of x2][label=left:$x_3$]{};
\node[state] (xdots) [below =of x3][label=left:$\vdots$]{};
\node[state] (xn) [below =of xdots][label=left:$x_n$]{};
% left ellipse
\node[fit={(a2)(xdots)},draw, ellipse,minimum width=3cm](left){};

\node[state] (b1) [right =of a1][label=right:$\beta_1$]{};
\node[state] (b2) [below =of b1][label=right:$\beta_2$]{};
\node[state] (b3) [below =of b2][label=right:$\beta_3$]{};
\node[state] (bdots) [below =of b3][label=right:$\vdots$]{};
\node[state] (bn) [below =of bdots][label=right:$\beta_n$]{};
\node[state] (y1) [below =of bn,yshift=-0.5cm][label=right:$y_1$]{};
\node[state] (y2) [below =of y1][label=right:$y_2$]{};
\node[state] (y3) [below =of y2][label=right:$y_3$]{};
\node[state] (ydots) [below =of y3][label=right:$\vdots$]{};
\node[state] (yn) [below =of ydots][label=right:$y_n$]{};
% right ellipse
\node[fit={(b2)(ydots)},draw, ellipse,minimum width=3cm](right){};

\path [dashed] (a1) edge (b1); \path [dashed] (b2) edge (a2);
\path [dashed] (b3) edge (a3); \path [dashed] (an) edge (bn);
\path (x1) edge (y1); \path (y2) edge (x2);
\path (y3) edge (x3); \path (xn) edge (yn);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the ellipses look much more beautiful than mine :)

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
\draw ($(an)+(0cm,-0.55cm)$) ellipse ({1.5cm} and {4cm});
\draw ($(bn)+(0cm,-0.55cm)$) ellipse ({1.5cm} and {4cm});
% \begin{large}
    \draw[color=white] ($(xn)+(0,-1cm)$) node {\color{black}$A$};
    \draw[color=white] ($(yn)+(0,-1cm)$) node {\color{black}$B$};
%\end{large}
```

to your Ti*k*Z drawing code.

[image]

You can of course change the numbers in the ellipse-drawing commands if you see that the ellipses are not good enough.

Hope this will help you!