# Drawing function relations

Tags: graphics, arrows, draw

Let's say I have three sets, A, B and C and some functions between them. How could I draw in LaTeX a diagram with arrows between these sets to show which functions relate them to which?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Can provide an sketch, how this relations should look? See `tikz-cd` package, it seems that it provide what you looking for.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have a look at question related to `tikz` and `sets`.  May be https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460422/15925 is relevant.  If you don't find what you need, please specify more clearly with a sketch of the type diagram you want.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{set/.style={circle,draw=#1,fill=#1!20}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
 |[set=red]|A \arrow[rr,bend left=10,"f"] \arrow[dr,bend left=10,"h"]
 & & |[set=DarkGreen]| B
 \arrow[ll,bend left=10,"f^{-1}"]  \arrow[dl,bend left=10,"g"]\\[3em]
 & |[set=blue]| C  \arrow[ur,bend left=10,"g^{-1}"]
  \arrow[ul,bend left=10,"h^{-1}"]&
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A way to make such a diagram with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

 \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, labelsep=2pt, linejoin=1}
 \begin{psmatrix}[mnode=circle, framesep = 10pt, fillstyle = solid, rowsep=2.4cm ]
%%% nodes 
[fillcolor=Lavender!60, linecolor=DarkMagenta] A & & [fillcolor=LavenderBlush, linecolor=FireBrick] B \\
    & [fillcolor=PapayaWhip, linecolor=SaddleBrown] C
 %%% arrows
\psset{arcangle=12, nodesep=-0.4pt, fillstyle=none, shortput=nab}
 \ncarc{1,1}{1,3}^{f }\ncarc{1,3}{1,1}^{f^{-1}}
 \ncarc{1,1}{2,2}^{h^{-1}} \ncarc{2,2}{1,1}^{h}
 \ncarc{1,3}{2,2}^{g} \ncarc{2,2}{1,3}^{g^{-1}}
 \end{psmatrix}
 \]\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]